# Can orientation preserving diffeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^d$ be presented by flowmap of dynamical systems? (time-varying case)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, approximation-theory, gm.general-mathematics

Because flowmaps are homeomorphic maps on a compact domain $\Omega$, I was wondering if there is any literature that proves that diffeomorphism $\Phi(x)$ can be expressed as a flowmap of a certain dynamical system?

that is, for any $\varepsilon>0$ does there exist $\dot z(t)=v(z(t))$ and end time $\tau>0$ with initial value $z(0)=x$ such that $\Phi(x)=\phi_v^\tau(x)$ or $\|\Phi(x)-\phi_v^\tau(x)\|<\varepsilon$ where $\phi_v^\tau(x)=z(\tau)$?

There is another version (time-fixed) of this question in [Can orientation preserving diffeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^d$ be presented by flowmap of dynamical systems?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458459/can-orientation-preserving-diffeomorphism-in-mathbbrd-be-presented-by-flow)

Comment: Flow maps are not necessarily diffeomorphisms; this is true only for compact manifolds while $R^n$ is not compact.

Answer (score 2):

Any orientation-preserving diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is [isotopic to the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79292/diffeomorphisms-of-mathbbrn). Differentiating the isotopy gives you a flow whose time-one is the diffeomorphism. See also [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95423/the-orientation-preserving-diffeomorphism-of-mathbb-rn).